# vscode omnisharp intellisense not working with dotnet 5.0 (target net5.0)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, intellisense, omnisharp

VsCode Omnisharp will not load projects that target net5.0. Everything seems to work fine with projects targeting lower versions of the SDK. Omnisharp fails loading the project with the following error:

**"The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at [https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks"](https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks%22)**

As far as I know there is no "Developer Pack" for 5.0 so I'm not sure what to do here. However, Omnisharp seems to be the only issue. The project will build and run without error. I guess that means the MSBuild is finding the framework. The Omnisharp extension is v1.23.8.

Relevant section and errors from the Omnisharp logs:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 1/10/2021, 5:49:52 PM
    Target: c:\Users\User Name\Documents\MyProject\Code\test3

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\User Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.23\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 7580

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.30406.217 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\User Name\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.23\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.30406.217 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
...

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\User Name\Documents\MyProject\Code\test3\test.web\test.web.csproj'.
```

Here is my dotnet --info output:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100     
 Commit:    5044b93829  

Runtime Environment:    
 OS Name:     Windows   
 OS Version:  10.0.18363
 OS Platform: Windows   
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0
  Commit:  cf258a14b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is Visual Studio installed on your PC and it is 16.7, OmniSharp is trying to use it's build tools to launch, but it is not 16.8 that supports .NET 5.0. Just update VS to the latest version and everithinng will go as you expect.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you Ivan.

Comment: Oh, my help helped :) Nice :) Good luck!

Comment: I get that this is a fix, but why should I have to update Visual Studio if I want to get Visual Studio Code to work with <next version>?

Comment: @Eliasar Yes, I have no option to update Visual Studio in my current situation, problem remains